# What type of inheritance is present in this example (apart from prototypal)

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have made the following example in javaScript. There is a constructor function from which I am creating an instance. Now, this instance gets 1 method directly from constructor function (printName) and one method it gets via prototype of constructor (printAge).

I can conclude that *printAge* can be called to be got via **prototypal Inheritance**, but does *printName* represent any kind of Inheritance (because it got automatically to newly created instance, is it classical inheritance or anything else?).

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

var person = function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
this.printName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
}
}
person.prototype.printAge = function(){
alert(this.age);
}

var person1 = new person("Jack", 29); 
person1.printName();
person1.printAge();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As, new instance got created, it gets *printName* from constructor function. Does it represent any kind of Inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

No, `printName` has nothing related to the inheritance. When you create an object via `person` function-constructor, each object gets its own copy of `printName` prpoerty which is a function. When I change that property for an object, for other ones it will not be changed.

```js
var person = function(name, age){
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age; 
   this.printName = function() {
       alert(this.name);
   }
};

person.prototype.printAge = function() {
   alert(this.age);
};

var person1 = new person("Jack", 29); 
var person2 = new person("Alex", 30); 
person1.printName = function() { console.log('Changed !!!'); };

person1.printName();
person2.printName();
```

So it is just a property which refers to a function. Similar property you have with name `age`, but `age` contains a primitive value.